# Get Image Object size in Python in Bytes - BadRequest Error in Azure

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, image, python-imaging-library

I have an image object that I've accepted via a streamlit interface. Here's its type: <class 'streamlit.uploaded_file_manager.UploadedFile'>

I need to get the size of this image in bytes or megabytes. The image is not stored on my device.
I tried using

```
def img_resize(image):
    img2 = Image.open(image)
    img_file = io.BytesIO()
    img2.save(img_file, 'png')
    image_file_size = img_file.tell()
    print(image_file_size)
    img2.close()

# This function connects to azure services and generates the resources and generates the results
def azure_result(image_name, image):
    img_resize(image)
```

Output:
**14386671**
2021-08-12 12:57:01.892 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path", line 1709, in read_in_stream
raise models.ComputerVisionOcrErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models._models_py3.ComputerVisionOcrErrorException: **Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'**

The file size printed is 14386671, the image size as per the system is 3.77 mb. When i further pass the image object to the Azure Cognitive Service, I get a bad request error.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the size of an object by storing them in a variable and printing it as below:

```
 print(sys.getsizeof(content))
```

Or we can add an extension to img_file as “. size”, this will get the actual size in bytes.

[image]

If we would like to get the file size in KB, MB and GB and convert them to bytes we can follow below conversion table:

[image]

We can add these extensions in img_resize(image) functions, we’ll be able to capture the correct bytes.

**Prerequisites** before you connect to Azure Cognito Service is to install the pip lib as below in terminal:

> pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision

Later below code gives us insight on how to connect to Azure Cognito Service:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models import VisualFeatureTypes
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

import os
region = os.environ['ACCOUNT_REGION']
key = os.environ['ACCOUNT_KEY']

credentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(key)
client = ComputerVisionClient(
    endpoint="https://" + region + ".api.cognitive.microsoft.com/",
    credentials=credentials
)
```

Can get more information from the [Python documentation](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision/) for Azure.